# healthcheck and application server with dependencies

Tags: service, architecture, microservices, health-monitoring, health-check

I have an application server which connects to two other services: Postgres and CouchDB.

The application server is deployed to autoscaling group which requires it to have a health endpoint: `/health`.

Now, `/health` endpoint returns 500 if one of the services is unreachable. Which kinda make sense but forces autoscaling group "noisy" because it constantly restarts the autoscaling group in a case of the issue.

Question: is the any best practice about '/health' check? should they check only underlying services or should they also check the dependant services?

Comment: I think your service should not be down or report to be down if your dependent services are not working. You service should be running by showing appropriate message

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the programming language and framework in which you have implemented your service.

For example, the java ecosystem has a spring boot framework and you can implement such functionality out of the box (spring boot actuator).

In your case, if you have a different programming stack, you generally need to implement an endpoint in your application that, when called, will return a successful response with http code 200, and you can also return, for example, the following json:

```
{ 
    "status": "UP" 
}
```

If your microservice is autoscaling in Kubernetes, then Kubernetes itself must check this endpoint for availability and, if not available, create a new instance of the microservice.

Regarding the dependency on services (Postgres and CouchDB), I would prefer the option that the microservice is available, in the case that services (Postgres and CouchDB) are not available, the microservice should return an error for the calling client, but the microservice should be available for the scaling system in anyway, regardless of the dependent services (Postgres and CouchDB).